# Subscribe / get notifications for all cards in a Trello board

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-organization, trello-boards

I’m working as a project manager and we are using Trello. As a team, we tend to write comments on a card in the comments field as notes / reminders to one another.

I only get notified of these if I explicitly subscribe to the card. Is there a way I can globally opt-in to notifications / subscriptions for all the cards in a board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subscribe to the whole board, lists or cards and get notifications of what is happening there. This page will give you more information: http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/930771-subscribing-to-cards-lists-and-boards

Note: if you have a highly active board it will become in a nightmare... :D

Answer (score 1):

To handle notifications, the Google Chrome Extension Notifier for Trello https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/notifier-for-trello/apgmgifljeljdmgkgklphgmckihimami?hl=en-US is helpful to my opinion.

Comment: If the link here becomes obsolete then the google extension as well and then my complete tip becomes worthless.